# How to create tree table on vue 3

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, vuejs3

I need to create a similar table.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbzmo.png)

The problem lies in the implementation of the tree.
I have `parent_id` and `children` arrays.

This look `[parent1, parent2 ,...]`

I need help in recursive component. How can I correctly implement a tree if there is an array for children?

Below is an example implementation. Please help fix if `children[parent_id]`.

My database looks like that: `[name, employee_id, subordinates [1,2,3,.. employee[id]], boss_id]`

**Tree component**

```html
<script>
// ...
const treeData = ref({ 
     name: 'My Tree', 
     children: [ 
         { name: 'hello' }, 
         { name: 'world' }, 
         { 
             name: 'child folder', 
             children: [ 
                 { 
                     name: 'child folder', 
                     children: [{ name: 'hello' }, { name: 'world' }] 
                 }, 
                 { name: 'hello' }, 
                 { name: 'world' }, 
                 { 
                     name: 'child folder', 
                     children: [{ name: 'hello' }, { name: 'world' }] 
                 } 
             ] 
         } 
     ] 
 }) 
  
 watchEffect(fetchDataFromServer); 
 </script> 
  
 <template> 
     <ul> 
         <TreeItem class="item" :model="items"></TreeItem> 
     </ul> 
  
 </template>



**TreeItem Component**




<script setup> 
 import { ref, computed } from 'vue' 
  
 const props = defineProps({ 
     model: Object 
 }) 
  
 const isOpen = ref(false) 
 const isFolder = computed(() => { 
     return props.model.subordinates && props.model.subordinates.length 
 }) 
  
  
  
 function toggle() { 
     isOpen.value = !isOpen.value 
 } 
  
 function changeType() { 
     if (!isFolder.value) { 
         props.model.children = [] 
     } 
 } 
  
 </script> 
  
 <template> 
     <li> 
         <div 
             :class="{ bold: isFolder }" 
             @click="toggle" 
             @dblclick="changeType"> 
             {{ model.name }} 
             <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ isOpen ? '-' : '+' }}]</span> 
         </div> 
         <ul v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder"> 
             <!-- 
               A component can recursively render itself using its 
               "name" option (inferred from filename if using SFC) 
             --> 
             <TreeItem 
                 class="item" 
                 v-for="model in model.children" 
                 :model="model"> 
             </TreeItem> 
         </ul> 
     </li> 
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, the most important things are **importing the Child component itself and determining the recursion boundary value.**

There are two import child component itself methods.

- import child component in child component

  ```
  <script setup>
  import About from './About.vue';

  const props = defineProps({
    info: Array,
  });
  </script>
  ```

the parent component like you's

- mount the component onto the Vue instance

By doing this, you can use it anywhere in this project.

```
  import App from './App.vue'
  import About from '@/pages/About.vue';
  const app = createApp(App)
  app.component('About', About)
```

Here is how to recurse and determine the recursion boundary value.

Using itself in the component is for enabling recursion. `v-if="item?.children?.length"` is for determining whether the recursion should end.

```
    <template v-for="item in info">
      <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
      <About v-if="item?.children?.length" :info="item.children" />
    </template>
```

This is full code.

```
  <template>
    <template v-for="item in info">
      <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
      <About v-if="item?.children?.length" :info="item.children" />
    </template>
  </template>

  <script setup>
  import About from './About.vue';

  const props = defineProps({
    info: Array,
  });
  </script>
```